# Обращение к элементам массива из словарей. Десериализация Json строки

Tags: c#, json, словари

В общем, дело обстоит так: нужно получать данные о карте игры с сервера. Сервер возвращает JSON- строку, в которой есть массив из словарей. Выглядит это примерно вот так:

> {"response":{"map_width":80,"map_height":80,"map_sp":5541,"objects":[{"type":1,"health":100},{"type":1,"health":100},{"type":1,"health":100},{"type":1,"health":100},{"type":1,"health":100}]}

Я могу спокойно получить все данные, кроме **objects**.
Объявление массива словарей такое: `public System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int>[] Field_Params;`.
Попытка получения данных из массива `Field_Params This_Field.Field_Params[0]["type"]` безуспешна т.к. я не могу обратиться к конкретному словарю.
Помогите, пожалуйста. Либо с тем, как получить данные из конкретного словаря в массиве, либо как лучше десериализовать возвращаемую сервером строку.
Код скрипта, который получает данные с сервера:

```
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Web_Queries : MonoBehaviour
// Класс Веб- запросов
{
    public class Web_Field
    // Поле с данными, получаемыми с сервера
    {
        // Ответ с сервера
        [JsonProperty("response")]
        public Dictionary<string, string>[] Response;
        // Ответ с сервера
        [JsonProperty("debug")]
        public string Description;
    }

    public Web_Field Get (string Url)
    // Get- запрос
    {
        // Объявляем новый экземпляр класса Web_Field
        Web_Field New_WF = new Web_Field();
        // Проверка подлинности сертефиката сайта
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        string Common_Response;
        // Создание нового объекта класса
        using (var Connection = new WebClient())
        {
            // Запрос на сайт
            Common_Response = Connection.DownloadString(Url);
        }
        New_WF = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Web_Field>(Common_Response);
        // Вернуть ответ с сервера
        return New_WF;
    }
}
```

Comment: Дополните сообщение кодом, в котором происходит десериализация из JSON

Comment: zuvladimir, дополнил

Comment: У вас значение  поля object десериализуется в строку. Попробуйте десериализовать все в Object. Замените      public Dictionary<string, string>[] Response; на      public Dictionary<string, object>[] Response;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Вариант 1:**

- Возьмем ваш `JSON` и прогоним его через [этот](http://json2csharp.com/) сайт.
- В ответ получаем структуру необходимых классов для грамотной десериализации `JSON`.
- Я смотрю у вас стоит JSON.NET, поэтому используем его, десериализируем строку в наш объект: `var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(file);`.
- Дальше без проблем можно получить доступ ко всему, что нам необходимо, например циклом пройтись по все данным из `objects`.

В итоге получаем что то вроде:

```
public class Object
{
    public int type { get; set; }
    public int health { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public int map_width { get; set; }
    public int map_height { get; set; }
    public int map_sp { get; set; }
    public List<Object> objects { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
}

var file = "{\"response\":{\"map_width\":80,\"map_height\":80,\"map_sp\":5541,\"objects\":[{\"type\":1,\"health\":100},{\"type\":1,\"health\":100},{\"type\":1,\"health\":100},{\"type\":1,\"health\":100},{\"type\":1,\"health\":100}]}}";
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(file);

foreach (var item in json.response.objects)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Type: {item.type}. Health {item.health}");
}
```

**Вариант 2 (без использования классов):**

- Парсим строку в `JObject`, методом `Parse`.
- Получаем небходимые данные, путем добавления некого индекса к нашему `JObject`.

Сам код:

```
var file = "{\"response\":{\"map_width\":80,\"map_height\":80,\"map_sp\":5541,\"objects\":[{\"type\":1,\"health\":100},{\"type\":1,\"health\":100},{\"type\":1,\"health\":100},{\"type\":1,\"health\":100},{\"type\":1,\"health\":100}]}}";
var json = JObject.Parse(file);

foreach (var item in json["response"]["objects"])
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Type: {item["type"]}. Health {item["health"]}");
}
```

Второй вариант хорошо подойдет маленькой утилите, которая использует небольшие данные `JSON`, на большом проекте его будет трудно изменять/масштабировать под сервер, ибо изменится значение на сервере - придется все строки переписывать и во всем коде. В первом варианте у вас есть структура, классы, которые соответствую тому, что есть на сервере в формате `JSON`, изменится у сервера что либо - быстро подправили класс и в нужном месте исправили ошибки. Что выбирать - решать вам.

Comment: Спасибо, Евгений! Все работает!

Comment: @GeorgeTuzikov Для спасибо существует "лайк" ответу, а если ответ Вас устраивает, то не забудьте отметить его "галкой".