# не получается десериализовать json строку и получить доступ к ней

Tags: c#, json, сериализация

json-строка:

```
"Information1": [
  {
   "Id1": 47569727,
   "date": 1517997958,
   "type": "buy",
   "keyboard": "blue",
   "Id2": 547013753,
   "quantity": "0.00019878",
   "price": "550",
   "amount": "23"
  }
 ]
}
```

десериализовал через json2csharp:

```
public class ABC
    {
        public int Id1 { get; set; }
        public int date { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string keyboard { get; set; }
        public int Id2 { get; set; }
        public string quantity { get; set; }
        public string price { get; set; }
        public string amount { get; set; }
    }

    public class List1
    {
        public List<ABC> Abc { get; set; }
    }
```

дальше не знаю как десериализовать, чтобы десериализовало без ошибок, так как я пытаюсь сделать так:

```
List<ABC> orderlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ABC>>(Convert.ToString(abc));
```

выдает ошибку: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[exmo.Form1+OpenOrders]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: Посмотрите данный [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/711699/220553), либо любой другой по десериализации JSON. Также не забывайте, что имена объектов и классов должны совпадать с тем, что есть в JSON. То есть смотрим предоставленные вами данные и видим, что есть некий массив `Information1`. Где у вас это реализовано? В классе `List1` надо переименовать. Также десериализовать не в `List<ABC>`, а в ваш класс `List1`.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте изменить строчку:

```
List<ABC> orderlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ABC>>(Convert.ToString(abc));
```

на

```
var orderlis = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Abc>>(abc);
```

вот [здесь](https://github.com/igorilyichyov/wk/tree/master/Coinmarket) работающий пример с использованием Newtonsoft, пример правда о другом, но там все то же самое, вдруг поможет

Comment: возможно ещё вместо List<Abc> должно быть ABC

Comment: к сожалению, не сработало: все значения либо null, либо равны 0.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить строчку:

```
List<ABC> orderlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ABC>>(Convert.ToString(abc));
```

на

```
var orderlis = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List1>(abc);
```

Comment: а как обращаться к коллекции List<ABC> ? у меня свойство Count = 0; а при переборе значений вообще ничего не выводит.

Comment: мне кажется, что строка вообще не десериализуется а улетает куда-то в небытие.

Comment: orderlis.Abs = List<ABC>

Comment: orderlis.Abs.Count()