# Как десериализовать нестандартный объект json.net?

Tags: c#, json.net

Дергая rest api мне приходит массив объектов у каждого из которых есть свойство-массив filters

```
    "filters":
[
    {
        "filterType": "PRICE_FILTER",
        "minPrice":"0.01000000",
        "maxPrice":"10000000.00000000",
        "tickSize":"0.01000000"
    },
    {
        "filterType":"LOT_SIZE",
        "minQty":"0.00001000",
        "maxQty":"10000000.00000000",
        "stepSize":"0.00001000"
    },
    {
        "filterType":"MIN_NOTIONAL",
        "minNotional":"10.00000000"
    }
]
```

Возможно ли вообще сделать десериализацию в классы, и можно ли вынести все эти свойства в класс на уровень выше вместо самого filters. Для парсинга я использую JObject.Parse(string)

```
    public class ExchangeInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("timezone")]
    public string Timezone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("serverTime")]
    public long ServerTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rateLimits")]
    public IEnumerable<LimitInfo> Limits { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("symbols")]
    public IEnumerable<SymbolInfo> Symbols { get; set; }
}


public class LimitInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("rateLimitType")]
    public string RateLimitType { get; set; }   // REQUESTS

    [JsonProperty("interval")]
    public string Interval { get; set; }        // MINUTE, SECOND, DAY

    [JsonProperty("limit")]
    public int Limit { get; set; }
}

public class SymbolInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("symbol")]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("baseAsset")]
    public string BaseAsset { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("baseAssetPrecision")]
    public int BaseAssetPrecision { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("quoteAsset")]
    public string QuoteAsset { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("quotePrecision")]
    public int QuotePrecision { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("orderTypes")]
    public IEnumerable<string> OrderTypes { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("icebergAllowed")]
    public bool IcebergAllowed { get; set; }

    // Что должно быть здесь?
    [JsonProperty("filters")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Filters { get; set; }
}
```

Ссылка на апи https://www.binance.com/api/v1/exchangeInfo
Мне нужно что бы у объекта SymbolInfo корректно заполнялось свойство Filters

Comment: И почему он не стандартный?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Обращение к элементам массива из словарей. Десериализация Json строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/711647/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%94%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-json-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, в массиве объекты разных типов, нормально сработает? Сам пока не могу проверить.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Да должно вполне нормально все быть.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Обновил вопрос

Comment: @МаксБурцев Я же вам указал точный ответ того, как десериализовать JSON. Посмотрите на его структуру внимательней, можете использовать сторонние [инструменты](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu). Что представляет из себя Filters? Это некий массив, каждый объект содержит другие объекты. Так создайте класс Filter и засуньте туда все внутренние объекты и там, где вы спрашиваете - указывайте `list<Filter> Filters`. Кстати, json.net без разницы с какой буквы указано свойство в классе, так что все JsonProperty у вас лишние (если конечно не отличается само название).

Comment: Если сделать так list<Filter>, то каким образом обработается различие в фитрах? Разные названия полей и их количество. Ту ссылку что вы дали там идет разбор ручками а не через классы.

Comment: @МаксБурцев Я дал вам ссылку, которая содержит 2 варианта работы с Json, 1 - классы, 2 - jobject. О каком различие идет речь?  Если вы про то, что где то есть строки, а где то нет, то json.net их оставит со стандартными значениями (null или false или 0, зависит от типа. Можете сделать их Nullable (int? Name), тогда будет все, что найдено иметь значение - остальное null.)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Таскать в классе пустые поля, заведомо зная что они никогда не будут использоваться, мне не позволяет моя вера :)

Comment: @МаксБурцев А вас кто то заставляет реализовать **всю** структуру? Я вам сказал как правильно, не более..

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Всю или не всю, даже одно поле, которое задействуется при одних данных и не задействуется при других, при этом занимает память - выглядит плохо, как архитектурно так и эстетически. Называть такое правильным подходом ошибка.

Comment: @МаксБурцев Вот тут я не соглашусь. Чем плохо иметь null значения, если их не дает сервер? Размер? Хм, да вроде Null = 4/8 байт, в наше время на байтах экономить глупо. Плохо, что отображается при написание кода? Тоже не соглашусь.. А вдруг вам нужно будет вывести что то, что когда нибудь не будет null, ведь сервер вам выдает данные динамические, они то есть, а то их и нет, это не статичные объекты Obj1 Obj2, это Obj[], причем сам Obj нам не известен. Давайте попробуем теперь подумать о удобстве....

Comment: @МаксБурцев У нас есть в json некое Value1, мы можем все это прочитать в класс и вывести как MyJson.Value1, а можем не заносить и прочитать как MyJson["Value1"]. В первом варианте вы 100% знаем, что такое объект у нас может быть, мы не знаем только его значение. Во втором случае объекта может и не быть вовсе, придется обрабатывать.. Ок. Предположим, что у нас сервер дает теперь json наш объект Value1 поменял название и превратился в Result1. Что тогда? В первом варианте нам достаточно пометить атрибутом наше значения (дав новое имя), во втором - придется искать все вызовы MyJson["Value1"].

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Представьте что у вас есть три объекта, и вы реализуете их в одном классе. Одни поля логически принадлежат одному объекту, другие другому. Это полнейший треш.

Comment: @МаксБурцев Давайте мы прекратим данный спор, у каждого свое мнение. Я лишь рассказал о том, как удобней и по мне правильней работать с JSON. Слушать меня или нет - дело ваше. А то мы с вами тут уже целый чат устроили!

Comment: @МаксБурцев не совсем понятно, в чем именно у вас проблема. Сериализация подразумевает близкую/схожую структуру между C#-классами и объектами в JSON. Если структура различается - вам придется делать ручной маппинг. Т.е. или руками выбирать нужные свойства, или десериализовать в "близкую к JSON" структуру классов C# и маппить полученные объекты в свое дерево "далеких от JSON" классов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз твои фильтры имеют проперти с разными именами и тебе не важно, что к ним нельзя будет обратиться по имени, а только по ключу, то можно сделать массив словарей.

```
public class SymbolInfo
{
    ...

    public IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,string>> Filters { get; set; }
}
```